# How to display a popover when user touches and holds a segment in segmented control (iOS)

Tags: ios, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to display a popover with additional options when a user touches (and holds) a segment in UISegmentedControl. How do I:

- detect the hold "gesture" on the segmented control.
- Display the popover with additional options on top of the selected segment

Thanks!

note a related question is:[iPad popover - How do you point to one segment in a segmented control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9748735/ipad-popover-how-do-you-point-to-one-segment-in-a-segmented-control)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You would need to create a View with those "Options" you want manually. Or you could use third party library such as [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/wypopovercontroller)
2. Add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to your UIView
3. Get the [position of the touch location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16618109/how-to-get-uitouch-location-from-uigesturerecognizer) and show the popover